# How to upload 2 images to two different folders (codeginiter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code to upload two images to the folder '/uploads'

How can I upload image no2 to another folder?

**Code**

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|svg' ;
$config['max_size'] = 2048;

$this->load->library('upload',$config);

if (! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile') && !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile2') ) {
    $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $post_image= 'noimage.png' ;
    $post_image2= 'noimage.png' ;
} else {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()) ;
    $post_image= $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $post_image2= $_FILES['userfile2']['name'];
}

$this->post_model->create_post($post_image,$post_image2);
redirect('../');
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the lib again with different $config path:

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config1);
```

Then do your upload

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config2);
```

Another upload with another path.

You can also use `initialize($config)`

Comment: Can you give me an example of my code because I am a beginner?

Comment: Just add a check `if($_FILES['userfile'])` and inside load your upload library with config1 .. and .. `if($_FILES['userfile1'])` and inside load your upload library with config2

Comment: It works, but i'm pretty sure you didn't do it correctly .. edit you question and add your new code.